# Does adding "synchronized" affect method overriding?

Tags: java, overriding, synchronized

my problem is that:

```
search_text.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
        @Override
        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
            ArrayList<Object> GPDMvalue = (ArrayList<Object>) multiSortList.getValue();
            ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> valueList = getDefaultValue(GPDMvalue);
            multiSortList.clear();
            if(getGPDMList().size()==0)return;
            multiSortList.setDataSource(getGPDMList());//new thread 1
            multiSortList.setDefaultOrAddValue(valueList);//new thread 2
        }
    });
```

when the text changing too fast ,and the thread 1 or thread 2 does't excute completely,and the maybe some problem,so i want add the `synchronized` like this 
`public synchronized void modifyText(ModifyEvent e)`,
is this still a override method and  will it work?

Comment: A similar discussion could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998335/is-synchronized-inherited-in-java. The key point is 'synchronized' is NOT part of the method signature. So the answer is yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `synchronized` keyword does not get in the way of overriding a method (it is still overridden) because the [method's signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) remains the same.

For more details see [JLS-§9.4.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.1.3)

Answer (score 5):

"Whether or not a method is synchronized is an implementation detail of the method. Synchronization isn't specified anywhere as a declarative contract - it's not like you can synchronize in interfaces, either.

How a class implements whatever thread safety guarantees it provides is up to it."

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805698/why-cant-an-abstract-method-be-synchronized)

Answer (score 3):

You can override a synchronized method and you can also remove synchronized keyword.

```
abstract class SynchronizedClass {
    public synchronized String myIterfaceMethod(String str){
        return str;
    }

}

public class OverrideSynchronozied extends SynchronizedClass{

    @Override
    public String myIterfaceMethod(String str){
        return str;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SynchronizedClass ss = new OverrideSynchronozied();
        System.out.println(ss.myIterfaceMethod("Class Instance"));
    }

}
```